# linq query to get list of friends

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I can't create a request to get a list of friends where name or surname like "param". The main requirement is that request has to take all friends with param of name or surname, not all and after that do `where`.
The exception returns to use `'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'`, but it does request before my `where` and it is bad idea, because if there are a lot of friends, then this is a big load.

Metthod in FriendshipRepository

```
    public IQueryable<User> GetAllFriends(int id)
    {
        var friends = _socialNetworkDbContext.Friends
            .Include(f => f.FriendUser.Profile)
            .Where(f => f.UserId == id || f.FriendId == id)
            .Select(f => f.UserId == id ? f.FriendUser : f.User)
            .AsQueryable();
        
        return friends;
    }
```

Then in service method to find friend by name or surname has this request

```
            string name = parts[0].ToLower();
            matchingUsers = _friendshipRepository.GetAllFriends(userDb.Id)
                .Where(user => EF.Functions.Like( user.Profile.Name.ToLower(), "%"+name+"%")
                    || EF.Functions.Like( user.Profile.Surname.ToLower(), "%"+name+"%"))
                .ToList();
```

And part

```
 .Where(user => EF.Functions.Like( user.Profile.Name.ToLower(), "%"+name+"%")
                    || EF.Functions.Like( user.Profile.Surname.ToLower(), "%"+name+"%"))
```

calls the Exception
`could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.`

So i need to do request that don't do request to all, but do request by my 'where' parameters. `'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList' after calling GetAllFriends(userDb.Id)` is bad idea, because if there are a lot of friends, then this is a big load.

So may be its normal to do like that, i don`t know, may be its only way to do this request?

Comment: Depending on the database used (and you should provide that, as well as the version of EF Core, in your question), `ToLower` isn't doing anything and removing it may allow translation. Generally once translated to SQL, the collation for the database column is expected to handle case sensitivity.

Comment: This is a strange query anyway. Would there ever be an `id` that  doesn't match a user but does match a Friend user? Seems impossible. And when it matches a UserId the method doesn't do what its name advertises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if EF can handle this properly:

```
.Select(f => f.UserId == id ? f.FriendUser : f.User)
```

and still treat it as an extendable `IQueryable`, however EF can build `LIKE %term%` queries using `string.Contains`.

You can try:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetAllFriendUsers(int id)
{
    var query = _socialNetworkDbContext.Friends
        .Where(f => f.UserId == id || f.FriendId == id)
        .Select(f => f.UserId == id ? f.FriendUser : f.User);
    
    return query;
}
```

then:

```
string name = parts[0].ToLower();
matchingUsers = _friendshipRepository.GetAllFriendUsers(userDb.Id)
.Where(u => u.Profile.Name.Contains(name)
    || u.Profile.Surname.Contains(name))
.ToList();
```

Notables: If returning `IQueryable` and using projection /w `Select` we don't need `Include` statements. The callers are free to project or eager load related data they particularly will need. We also don't need to cast it as `AsQueryable` as it will return `IQueryable`.

The caveats here are that your database is set up for a Case Insensitive collation (I.e. a *CI** Collation)  on the Name and Surname. If the collation is Case Sensitive (*CS**) then add the `.ToLower()` before `.Contains(...)`.

If the Query still doesn't work then you might have to adjust the Repository to return Friends then build the sub-querying to check through the two user references:

```
public IQueryable<Friend> GetAllFriends(int id)
{
    var query = _socialNetworkDbContext.Friends
        .Where(f => f.UserId == id || f.FriendId == id);
    
    return query;
}

string name = parts[0].ToLower();
matchingUsers = _friendshipRepository.GetAllFriends(userDb.Id)
.Where(f => (f.UserId == userDb.Id 
        && (f.User.Profile.Name.Contains(name)
            || f.User.Profile.Surname.Contains(name)))
    || (f.FriendId == userDb.Id 
        && (f.FriendUser.Profile.Name.Contains(name)
            || f.FriendUser.Profile.Name.Contains(name))))
.Select(f => f.FriendId == userDb.Id ? f.FriendUser : f.User)
.ToList();
```

The difference here is that we return Friends, then build the query expression to check the User name or the FriendUser name depending on which Id matched.

Note that because you want to conditionally load either the Friend.User or the Friend.FriendUser this will complicate things if you want to eager load related details like the applicable user's profile. For example you can try something like:

```
.Include(f => f.FriendId == userDb.Id ? f.FriendUser.UserProfile : f.User.UserProfile)
```

However I don't believe that kind of conditional in an `Include` works.

If reading data and you want User and UserProfile details I would recommend using the `Select` to project a view model so that you can select details from the applicable user and user profile. Otherwise I would recommend designing the repository call and business logic to be explicit about whether the ID being used is a FriendId or a UserId rather than trying to either/or conditionally in a single method. If your code knows it is loading a user based on a Friend ID or based on a User ID then you can be deterministic about the entity and related entities to eager load. As a general rule, conditional logic like that should be avoided as much as possible as it can make the code a lot harder to follow at a glance and leaves the door open to obscured little bugs.